# Handling rendering delays gracefully

Tags: performance-tuning, front-end, guidelines, scheduling

I moved the second issue to a separate topic: [162013](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/162013/5478)

Please run the code sample

[image]

As you can see there is a delay between the moment the calculation is finished and when the graphics is shown. And during this delay the FrontEnd is frozen, even progress indicator does not work.

It will be worse for more complicated / bigger examples. Sometimes you can predict this and e.g. rasterize / but sometimes not.

The bottom line is: users are confused.

#### Question

Is there a better way to deal with this delay other than putting big "rendering" message on top just before the calculation is finished?

---

The `Pause[]` in the code below is only to let `ProgressIndicator` spin a little longer, for illustration.

#### Code sample

```
DynamicModule[{processing1 = False, processing2 = False},
 
 data = panel1 = {};
 n = 5 10^4;
 update1[] := panel1 = Graphics[Line@data, Frame -> True];
 
 Grid[{{
    Button["run me",
     
     processing1 = True;
     data = RandomReal[1, {n, 2}];
     Pause[1];
     update1[];
     processing1 = False;
     
     ,
     Method -> "Queued",
     ImageSize -> 100 {1, 1}
     ]
    ,
    Dynamic[
     If[processing1, 
      Dynamic@ProgressIndicator[Appearance -> "Indeterminate"],
      panel1],
     , TrackedSymbols :> {processing1}]
    
    
    
    }}, BaseStyle -> CacheGraphics -> False]
 ]
```

Comment: I don't have time to respond thoughtfully to this.  But briefly...if the delay is in the front end and cannot be moved out of the front end, then it's hopeless.  The two typical examples where the delay really can't be moved out of the front end are slow visual rendering (i.e., that the FE is literally being slowed down by calls to the drawing system), or long MathLink transmission times.  In your case, you're being slowed down by the former...this is empirically observable by seeing how sluggish the graphic is when resizing.

Comment: One could imagine, running a service front end to do the rendering and turn the result into a bitmap, which could then be communicated back to the master front end quite efficiently.  This can be done fairly simply with the parallel evaluation commands.  I leave that an exercise to the reader.  Ultimately, this is just off-loading the rendering to another process, which is the same qualification I gave in my comment above.

Comment: @JohnFultz This problem arises in real-world UI's for customers. And it would be so sad to give up with CDF, or the standard FrontEnd to do this kind of smooth predictable UI's which is needed. Will there be a better FrontEnd or should we all move to the cloud and JavaScript?

Comment: Re `FinishDynamic[]`, to be perfectly honest, I'm not going to claim to completely understand how it behaves.  It has, on occasion, defied my expectations as well, and I've never run it to ground.

Comment: @JohnFultz yes, that will do if you have a static output, and I will try to prepare this workaround as an answer. It gets complicated when you have EventHandlers etc inside.

Comment: @RolfMertig the fundamental problem is that there is one thread which is the main point of contention in the desktop FE.  This is also true in JavaScript.  It's a major problem for JavaScript that wasn't even partially mitigated until web worker support got traction in all the major browsers.  Modulo the possibility of using web workers, the set of issues with managing JavaScript + back end computation mirrors to a surprising degree the issues that arise with the desktop FE + kernel back end.  I'm not going to pretend the current situation is ideal, but I'm not making any promises, either.

Comment: ...and there is no magic fairy dust to sprinkle.  While we do now live in a world where you can count on web workers existing, that comes with a real expense of upping the complexity of the resulting JS.  E.g., the web workers can't access the DOM and have to act by message passing with the main JS thread.